# Google Sheets IMPORTDATA with encoding

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a file URL in the following format:

`http://.../exchangerate.txt`

I cannot use `IMPORTDATA` because the file is in encoding:

`UTF-16`

it gives me bad data:

> �n�u�l�l�

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Please try the script:

```
function importwithencoding(url, encoding, delim) {
  if (delim === "tab") { delim = '\t'; }
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var csv = data.getContentText(encoding); 
  return Utilities.parseCsv(csv, delim);
}
```

Use it as a custom formula in a sheet:

`=importwithencoding("http://.../exchangerate.txt", "UTF-16", "tab")`